# is there any optimized way to avoid loops?

Tags: imap, synchronization

Hi I am implementing Email Client Application. My Application is like web based Application. I have xxxxxx number of users Mail Credentials. I need to sync for them without using any looping concept. It should immediately reflect when something changes in Mail Server. IMAP IDLE will not helpful seems it is only giving New Email Arrival. I want to get Each and Every changes from Mailserver. Without using any looping, is there alternate way to do this. I need to do this in Generalized Approach. bcoz Something supported in Gmail but not supported in yahoo...
so generalized approach is appreciated.

Comment: any reason to avoid loops?

Comment: If you're using PHP you're stuck because (generally) you can't do background processing in it, is this the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: as i told, i want to make the changes immediately to my Client Application. I want to follow some approach like Listener, it should listen the changes occur in Mail server and notify to my application to update those changes.if i use loop, we can't predict completion time. when increase user in my application...

Comment: I already doing this with background jobs. My main focus on this is to avoid background jobs.

Comment: How many mail credentials do you have, and why can't you use a loop? Can you provide us with a sample of the code you currently have?  What servers do you need to deal with? You mention gmail and yahoo, are there any others?

Answer (score 1):

The optimized way to avoid loops is called IDLE. That's why it was specified and implemented. If there had been a way to do what you want without IDLE, then IDLE would not have been necessary in the first place.

Comment: Yes arnt i accept IDLE will do that. But it is giving the notification of only New Email Arrivals and deleted emails. but I want to get Notification of All the changes and same time it should not be specific to only particular mailbox. i want to be notified from all the mailbox. I know this can be done by NOTIFY but seems Gmail/Yahoo not supporting this feature. I want to archive this by using some Generalized Approach..

Comment: That's what you wish, yes. Could you, in the future, restrict yourself to programming questions, and keep your impossible wishes to yourself?

Comment: @arnt: see my answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

Your questions show a lack of familiarity with a protocol, and a weird entitlement to features that do not exist.  I suspect very much you have bitten off way more than you can chew.

Read [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) cover to cover.  This is the IMAP4Rev1 specification.  This is all you can expect, in general, from general servers on the internet, and no more.  And sometimes, not even that much*.  IMAP4 is fundamentally a single-folder protocol.  You can only get information and messages for one folder at a time.  It is up to you to interrogate the server for what information you want; it is not obligated to tell you anything you did not specifically ask for.

Writing real, full-featured, broadly-compatible email clients is *difficult*.  Start by writing a client that can synchronize one user and one folder, on baseline IMAP.  Implement extensions to make this more efficient when available: IDLE, CONDSTORE, etc.  Then move on to many folders, and many users.

Also understand that this dream of thousands of users is also going to run into serious logistical issues.  No server on the internet is going to allow you to log in hundreds of times without having gotten an agreement ahead of time.  You will cause your users extreme headaches when they get mysteriously locked out of their accounts for logging in from 'weird' places.  In the case of google, this can be mitigated with OAuth, but that will only take you so far before they become interested in what you're doing.

Also, good reading is [RFC 2683: IMAP Implementation Recommendations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2683).

*: There are many servers that do not properly support SEARCH, several that do not send UIDNEXT on SELECT, Yahoo won't allow you to keep a persistent connection or give any updates at all without reconnecting, etc.

Comment: yes Max, whatever you said above i know, i red RFC 3501 completely... That is what i am trying to overcome those problem and do a good Application...

Comment: Then why do you keep asking for things that clearly do not exist?  If you know that you can only synchronize a folder at a time, why do you ask how not to do that?  You have to switch folders and synchronize them separately.  You may have to fetch flags whenever you connect.  You not be able to do IDLE.  If you are using Google, you may (depending on user settings) be able to just sync their All Mail folder instead, but prepared to fall back if you can't access it or don't see it.